# What support does Windows Phone have for emergency calling?

Tags: find-my-phone

I read recently ([L.A. Times article](http://articles.latimes.com/2013/aug/13/local/la-me-ln-911-caller-location-20130812)) that cellular phone networks have not been doing a good job with emergency 911 calls in the U.S.  The dispatchers who receive the calls often do not receive location information that they are supposed to.

I'm wondering if the "emergency call" button on my Windows Phone does anything to assist with locating the phone when the emergency call is made.  Or does it just act as a speed dial button for 911?

Is there any linkage to the "find my phone" feature?

Comment: It should call the local emergency number of that country, 911 in the states and 112 in Europe.

Comment: @NeilTurner Most operators in the world maps both 911, and 110-113 range to emergency numbers, regardless of what the local default is. Most smartphones, including Windows Phone, will also automatically map 911 to 112 in Europe, and vice versa.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen-MSFT Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 1):

When you click the button, all it does is bring up a dial pad which you can dial emergency with. It does NOT automatically call 911 for you.